# How to make auto expandable home page banner like

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uistoryboard, parallax

I have used the separate banner image and scroll view for category sections and tableview for records.

Need to make all things scrollable to topside and when the scroll position reached the top position category section would fixed at top position and the table view records would continue scrolling and once the scroll down all the object would displayed to their original position back to back well which is normally happen in android apps and whatsapp profile page.[image]

Please share your answer if you have done like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here is the link for [DTParallaxTableView](https://github.com/toandk/DTTableView)

[QMBParallaxScrollViewController](https://github.com/quemb/QMBParallaxScrollViewController)

This Library same you want [MXSegmentedPager](https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager)

May this helps lot.

Comment: After compiling this app shows Apple Mach-O Linker Error Linker command failed with exit code 1

Comment: @CJIOSDeveloper I already download this source code and test my side it's working perfectly.

Comment: @CJIOSDeveloper I edit the answer and adding more library for your use.

Comment: i have tried MXSegmentedPager already but POD issue would come and now i have use the command in terminal pod try MXSegmentedPager and project downloaded and open automatically after sometime but when running its showing errors.   > iff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: hi @CJIOSDeveloper. pod try should work with objc/swift examples, use the last cocoapods. Otherwise, clone the repo and run pod install on examples.

Comment: @Maxime Epain , After run pod install on examples  pod files installed but running the workspace and compiling error is Parse Issue, Semantic Issue etc.